# how should I switch from rsync to btrfs-send btrfs-receive

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I got quite a big number of files and rsync has become a bit long to process my 20To Data to rync to a distant site, even if there is not such changes.

I would like to switch to btrfs send / receive as the two filesystem are btrfs, but at this time the volumes have been filled in some differents way so I am sure that blocks are not distributed the same way on both filesystem.

let's say I don't care about previous snapshot. I would like to know how I can replace a rsync sync between two site with btrfs send/receive. isn't it not too late now that I have a big amount of data or is there still a chance to switch.
In fact I presume (but I don't know) that the first btrfs-send/receive will rewrite completely the file system, in that case it would require to write about 20To on a low speed link. A situation that I will avoid completely. if this is required I will bring back the distant filesystem to local, make a full btrfs-send and than send the 2sd filesystem to distant and btrfs-send snapshot.

let me know how one could setup the replacement.

Comment: It might be that I'm not a native English speaker, but the question is a bit unclear to me; do you want to use `btrfs send/receive` like you use `rsync -u` between two locations?

Comment: Today , I use rsync, and it is long to sync  file from one side to the other. Tomorrow I want to use btrfs-send/receive instead. So i ask how to switch from rsync to btrfs-send/receive

Comment: Hmmm... AFAIK, it's not possible to use `btrfs sync/receive` to "sync" data between two machines. I think you might want to check out [btrbk](https://github.com/digint/btrbk), [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), or just plain use `rsync` with the `-zu` flags; `z` compresses the files and `u` just updates files that are more recent from - source to dest - and adds new files (if any) whilst leaving the old ones behind.